# Simple Inequality Proof

Tags: inequality

Prove the following inequality

$\ xX + yY  \leq  \sqrt{ x^2 + y^2}\cdot\sqrt {X^2 + Y^2}$

where $x, y, X$ and $Y$ are real numbers.

Comment: Hint: proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) for $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the "vectors" $(x,y)$ and $(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 2):

(1) Make square both sides

(2) Use the fact that $$2AB \leq A^2+ B^2$$